# Converting table layout to div equivalent

Tags: html, css, html-table

I currently have a table:

```
<table id="blockcontainer">
    <tr>
        <td class="topleftgrey"></td>
        <td class="topcentergrey">
            <span class="sharemedium">FAQ</span> <span class="headingmedium">Categories</span>
        </td>
        <td class="toprightgrey"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="middleleft"></td>
        <td class="middlecenter">
            some content goes here
        </td>
        <td class="middleright"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="bottomleft"></td>
        <td class="bottomcenter"></td>
        <td class="bottomright"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

With CSS:

```
#blockcontainer {width:100%;}
#blockcontainer .topleft{background:url(../../Content/Images/top-left.png) no-   repeat;width:8px;height:52px;}
#blockcontainer .topcenter{background:url(../../Content/Images/top-center.png) repeat-x;height:52px;color:#fff;padding-left:5px;font-size: large;text-align: left;}
#blockcontainer .topright{background:url(../../Content/Images/top-right.png) no-repeat;width:8px;height:52px;}
#blockcontainer .topleftgrey{background:url(../../Content/Images/top-leftgrey.png) no-repeat;width:8px;height:52px;text-align: left;}
#blockcontainer .topcentergrey{background:url(../../Content/Images/top-centergrey.png) repeat-x;height:52px;padding-left:5px;font-size:large;text-align: left;}
#blockcontainer .toprightgrey{background:url(../../Content/Images/top-rightgrey.png) no-repeat;width:8px;height:52px;text-align: left;}
#blockcontainer .middleleft{background:url(../../Content/Images/middle-left.png) repeat-y;width:8px;}
#blockcontainer .middlecenter{background-color:#fff;padding:5px;}
#blockcontainer .middleright{background:url(../../Content/Images/middle-right.png) repeat-y;width:8px;}
#blockcontainer .bottomleft{background:url(../../Content/Images/bottom-left.png) no-repeat;width:8px;height:8px;}
#blockcontainer .bottomcenter{background:url(../../Content/Images/bottom-center.png) repeat-x;height:8px;}
#blockcontainer .bottomright{background:url(../../Content/Images/bottom-right.png) no-repeat;width:8px;height:8px;}
```

That looks like this:

[image]

The problem I am having is that there are multiple tables like this on one page (this table acts as my content containers), and due to the way that tables load in a browser, the page loads terribly slow.

I know converting this to a div will make the world of difference, but I am unable to convert this table structure to an equivalent div stricture.

Sorry for posting a "do it for me" question, but multiple attempts at this has already left a piece of my keyboard on my wall. :)

[Here is the jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/TxNk4/)

Comment: Can you mock it up in jsfiddle for us with links to the images?

Comment: sure... http://jsfiddle.net/TxNk4/

Comment: i wish i could mark more than one answer as correct :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aniket beat me to it, however I believe mine is a more accurate CSS rendition of your current image and table-based code:

http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/YyHKf/

It uses CSS3 `box-shadow` (along with the browser prefixed versions for compatibility) and gradient backgrounds (which doesn't work in Opera only, but that's an easy addition).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container" id="container1">
    <div class="header" id="header1">
        FAQ Categories
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="content1">
        <div>content
            <div class="right">5
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px#888;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    background: #fff;
    width:100%;
}

.header {
    padding:5px;
    background:#eeeeee;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#eeeeee');
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#eee));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fff,  #eee);
  height:40px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom:1px #888 solid;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px#888;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #888;
}

.content {
    padding:0 5px 10px 5px;
    margin-top:3px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
}

.content div {
    padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-bottom:1px #ccc solid;
}

.content .right {
    float:right;
    border:none;
}
```

Comment: this makes me feel like a complete idiot:) thanx. but it's also insanley accurate and flexible

Answer (score 2):

The below uses floated div's and negative margins. I also wrapped the content with the `middleleft` and `middleright` elements so they would inherit the height of the content itself and stretch the borders to the appropriate height.

Note, due to the negative margins, you'll probably want to look at the margins put on the `middlecenter` element.

```
.blockcontainer .topleft {
    background: url(http://www.effortshare.com/Content/Images/top-left.png) no-repeat;
    width: 8px;
    height: 52px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -8px;
}
.blockcontainer .topcenter {
    background: url(http://www.effortshare.com/Content/Images/top-center.png) repeat-x;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: large;
    text-align: left;
}
.blockcontainer .topright {
    background: url(http://www.effortshare.com/Content/Images/top-right.png) no-repeat;
    width: 8px;
    height: 52px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -8px;
}
.blockcontainer .topleftgrey {
    background: url(http://www.effortshare.com/Content/Images/top-leftgrey.png) no-repeat;
    width: 8px;
    height: 52px;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -8px;
}
.blockcontainer .topcentergrey {
    background: url(http://www.effortshare.com/Content/Images/top-centergrey.png) repeat-x;
    height: 52px;
    font-size: large;
    text-align: left;
}
.blockcontainer .toprightgrey {
    background:url(http://www.effortshare.com/Content/Images/top-rightgrey.png) no-repeat;
    width: 8px;
    height: 52px;
    text-align: left;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -8px;
}
.blockcontainer .middleleft {
    background: url(http://www.effortshare.com/Content/Images/middle-left.png) repeat-y;
    margin-left: -8px;
    overflow: visible;
}
.blockcontainer .middlecenter {
    padding: 5px 8px 5px 8px;
}
.blockcontainer .middleright {
    background: url(http://www.effortshare.com/Content/Images/middle-right.png) repeat-y;
    background-position: right top;
    margin-right: -8px;
    overflow: visible;
}
.blockcontainer .bottomleft {
    background: url(http://www.effortshare.com/Content/Images/bottom-left.png) no-repeat;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -8px;
}
.blockcontainer .bottomcenter {
    background: url(http://www.effortshare.com/Content/Images/bottom-center.png) repeat-x;
    height: 8px;
}
.blockcontainer .bottomright {
    background:url(http://www.effortshare.com/Content/Images/bottom-right.png) no-repeat;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -8px;
}

<div class="blockcontainer">
    <div class="header topcentergrey">
        <div class="topleftgrey"></div>
        This is a title
        <div class="toprightgrey"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="middleleft">
        <div class="middleright">
            <div class="middlecenter">
                <div class="row">
                    <div>This is left</div>
                    <div class="right">Right</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div>This is left</div>
                    <div class="right">Right</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div>This is left</div>
                    <div class="right">Right</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottomleft"></div>
    <div class="bottomright"></div>
    <div class="bottomcenter"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/FtCLJ/4/

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer my question, if you look at the table style, you will see there are already very specific layout requirements, changing that specific layout to make use of divs is where the problem lies.

Comment: Are you talking about implementing the background images themselves?

Comment: this is a scaleable table with images right around it, content size can change in both width and height, background images also needs to be implemented

Comment: @Dusty Roberts: Would you be willing to implement a CSS3 design (with cross-browser compatibility of course)?

Comment: @Purmou, at this point in time i would consider anything (that is cross browser compatible). as long as i don't have to use tables for this specific scenario

Comment: @Dusty - See my edit. Note the middle left and right elements I still haven't figured out how to get them to be the height of the box.

Comment: @Purmou, Genius, so far its exactly what i am looking for.

Comment: @Dusty - See my edit about the heights. May not be as nifty as the CSS-only renderings, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Check this fiddle -
http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/ePARN/

I have removed the use of all images, and it's pure CSS.

### HTML

```
<div id="blockcontainer">
    <dl>
        <dt class="title">FAQ Categories</dt>
        <dt>Some content goes here</dt>
        <dt>Some content goes here</dt>
        <dt>Some content goes here</dt>
        <dt>Some content goes here</dt>
    </dl>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#blockcontainer {
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#blockcontainer dl dt.title {
    font-size: 1.25em;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ddd, #fff); /* FF 3.6+ */  
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ddd, #fff); /* IE10 */  
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #eee), color-stop(50%, #ddd), color-stop(100%, #fff)); /* Safari 4+, Chrome 2+ */  
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ddd, #fff); /* Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+ */  
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ddd, #fff); /* Opera 11.10 */  
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ddd', endColorstr='#ffffff'); /* IE6 & IE7 */  
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ddd', endColorstr='#ffffff')"; /* IE8+ */  
    background: linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ddd, #fff); /* the standard */  
}

#blockcontainer dl {
}

#blockcontainer dl dt {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should be using Ul and Li (to be more semantic) for navigation not table tags. Using table will just screw up the entire layout.
If I were you, I would opt for [960 gs](http://www.960.gs/) and choose grid_1

```
<div class="grid_1">
<div id="sidenavi">
<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li>FaQ</li>
<li>some here</li>
<li>others here</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

and my css would say:

```
#sidenavi ul li
{
#background ......
}
```

I hope it works out for u.
The code would be shorter, efficient and as per semantics :)

Comment: this is not navigation, this is a layout of a "content container"